# Laravel - put custom message under message key not in errors after request validation fail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made CustomRequest and using it in my controller:

```
someMethod(CustomRequest $request){}
```

after my validation fail i get this

> {message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {token: ["Token is required"]}}

is it possible to get this:

> {message: "custom message only for this CustomRequest fail.", errors: {token: ["Token is required"]}}

Answer (score 0):

The FormRequest object has this function for defining custom messages:

```
/**
 * Get custom messages for validator errors.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the messages() function to overwrite them `app/Http/Requests/YourRequest.php`

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'Er, you forgot your email address!',
        'email.unique' => 'Email already taken m8',
    ];
}
```

Reference: [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-custom-error-messages?page=1)

Author Name: [bashy](https://laracasts.com/@bashy)